# Hover state when entering site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, state

I'm having a problem with hover on images.

When entering the site the hover-state is active, but it shouldn't be until a mouseover-event.
When moving the mouse over the images the hover effect disappears and functions properly.

Here's the code-snippet: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JwztH/

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/JwztH/4/

Comment: Since, answer is already given, I have some suggestions for your plugin.

`1-Use on in place of live.2-return this from plugin.3-You can pass two functions to hover, in that case you need not to check event type`

Comment: As has been mentioned, `live` is deprecated and you really shouldn't be using it. http://liveisdeprecated.com

Comment: Thanks James for the page +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set  `display: none;` in the css on the items you don't want to have visible at start (for example `ol li div.cykel a.cykel-hover`).

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/txYc4/

Comment: I hate when the answer is so darn simple! - I've been starring myself blind on this problem for hours now.. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Tell yourself that that's better than to have to rebuild the whole site !

Comment: @Dipaks : oh yes, I forgot to add jQuery while duplicating the fiddle. Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<a href="#" class="cykel-hover" style="opacity: 0;">` this works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/mavrick3/JwztH/3/

Answer (score 0):

add - `$('.cykel-hover').hide();`

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JwztH/5/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you have

```
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
```

set in `a.cykel-hover` but it will work only in IE. For other browsers, add `opacity: 0` (and probably versions with vendor-specific prefixes); http://jsfiddle.net/JwztH/6/

Answer (score 0):

you can put `$(this).find(settings.target).stop().fadeTo(settings.duration, 0);` to apply to all the fadeable

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/v937A/